# Time, TimerTask java

Tags: java, таймер

Есть метод `set()` который  задает значение `enum - STARTED`. Как сделать так, чтобы через определенное время `duration` значение `enum` задалось как `FINISHED`. В этот период можно вызывать другой метод `doSomething()` и в зависимости от состояния `enum (STARTED или FINISHED)` в консоль выводятся разные сообщения. Думаю, что нужно использовать `timer.schedule(timerTask, long delay)`, но не знаю как именно.

Comment: Напишите код который это делает.

Comment: public  void set(State state){ state=State.STARTED;}

Comment: Что выполняется в `timerTask`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

enum SomeEnum {
    STARTED,
    FINISHED
}

public class Example {
    private volatile SomeEnum someEnum;
    private static int DURATION = 5000;

    public void set() {
        someEnum = SomeEnum.STARTED;

        new Timer(true).schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                someEnum = SomeEnum.FINISHED;
            }
        }, DURATION);
    }

    public boolean doSomething() {
        switch (someEnum) {
            case STARTED:
                System.out.println("Tick");
                return true;
            case FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Buy");
                return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.set();
        while (obj.doSomething()) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```